# React Native using variables in styles

Tags: react-native

I am using a styles file to handle everything relating to that within my application. I am trying to set a style based off of a variable that is previously declared however I am unsure of the syntax needed.

```
render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
        <View style={styles.${params.key}}>

        </View>
    );
}
```

The line in question is the style={styles.${params.key}} but that line is not properly compiling. Not sure on the correct syntax of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's going to be something like that:

```
styles[params.key]
```